How do I hide the XR controller when the player grabs an object in Unity XR?
I recently switched from Unity XR interaction toolkit 2.4 to XR interaction toolkit 3.0.
I noticed that in the XR Direct Interactor (the grab interactor) the option to hide the controller after a grab disappeared. Strangely it IS mentioned in the documentation, see the link.
In the screenshots you can see the option is no longer there. How do I hide the XR controllers after the user grabs an item?


